# Pull reports from Shopify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I am trying to pull reports automatically from shopify admin portal. From source page I can see that javascript function makes this call -

```
var shopifyQL = "**SHOW** quantity_count, total_sales BY product_type, product_title, sku, shipping_city, traffic_source, source, variant_title, host, shipping_country, shipping_province, day, month, referrer FROM **products** SINCE xxx UNTIL yyy ORDER BY total_sales DESC";

  var options = {"category":"product_reports","id":wwwwww,"name":"Product Report by SKU","shopify_ql":"SHOW quantity_count, total_sales BY product_type, product_title, sku, shipping_city, traffic_source, source, variant_title, host, shipping_country, shipping_province, day, month, referrer FROM products SINCE xxxx  UNTIL yyyy ORDER BY total_sales DESC","updated_at":"zzz"};
```

However looking at the product API (https://docs.shopify.com/api/product) I do not see most of the attributes.  I am assuming some join tables or seperate calls to the model.   Also I tried to pull single sku information but it pulls everything.

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:variants => {:sku => 'zzzz'}})
```

Does anybody had any experience to work with reports??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would go like this for you. First off, if you pull products, you have do so in chunks of 250. The :all symbol gives you up to 250. Supplying a page and limit parameter would help there.

Second, you cannot filter by SKU. Instead, download all the products, and then inside each product are the variants. A variant has a SKU, so you'd search that way.

Doing that, you could setup your own nice reference data structure, ready to be used in reporting as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you David! That seems like a case here.

Comment: Hi David, where I can get information about quantity_count, total_sales BY product_type? Are they custom methods?

Comment: just add those up yourself. If the native reports don't cut it, you're on your own... download orders.. and do some math...

Comment: Thank you David!  I would like to give you points but it does not allow me. :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab the data from the api and play with it. The available objects are clearly stated on the Shopify API docs. Admin dashboard data can't be pulled like the way you seem to envision unless you play with JavaScript injection (tampermonkey...) which is highly not recommended.

Comment: Thank you Alex!  I started playing with it. I thought that shopify has those complex relations which would allow much easier to pull info.

Comment:  Shopify's API is one of the best you'll ever find!